# R- Rtools not working

Tags: r, windows

I 'm trying to run the find_rtools() function.
The `library(devtools)` command is running fine but when i run `find_rtools()` it is throwing a warning:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
>
> Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-    project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
>
> find_rtools(T)
>   Scanning path...
>   Scanning registry...
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
>
> Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-  project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().

I need to fix this as i neeed to install the :

```
pacman::p_install_gh("trinker/qdap")
```

> Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   *** arch - x64
>   Warning: package 'qdapDictionaries' was built under R version 3.2.0
>   Warning: package 'qdapRegex' was built under R version 3.2.0
>   Warning: package 'qdapTools' was built under R version 3.1.3
>   Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) :
>     bytecode version mismatch; using eval
>   Warning: package 'RColorBrewer' was built under R version 3.1.3
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
>
> Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-  project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
>   ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
>   * removing 'C:/Program_Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/qdap'
>   * restoring previous 'C:/Program_Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/qdap'
>   Error : Command failed (1)
>
> The following packages were not able to be installed:
>   qdap
>   Warning message:
>   In p_install_gh("trinker/qdap") :
>     The following may have incorrect capitalization specification:
>     qdap

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed Rtools?

Comment: Yes , i have installed Rtools. The path of Rtools is :  C:\Rtools. My working directory is present in D drive.

Comment: Should I store  Rtools in some specific folder for the find_rtools() function to work?

Comment: You need to put Rtools "into the PATH". Press ctrl+window key and start typing "environment" (edit system environment variables). Graphically: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: What if I don't have the permissions to place Rtools into this path? Is there any other way that i can do it?

Comment: The package seems to be installed locally. --> 'Download the zip ball or tar ball, decompress and run R CMD INSTALL on it' (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/README.html). However JAVA_HOME is not set as well. Have you installed it? It the rJava package is required, it would fail.

Comment: If you don't have the permissions you should ask your system admin to install Rtools for you.

Comment: @JaehyeonKim is (IMO) onto the problem.  It's a Java issue I believe. This bit may be helpful: http://trinker.github.io/qdap/vignettes/qdap_vignette.html#install

Comment: I have downloaded the zip ball and decompressed it. How to run R CMD INSTALL. Sorry for asking stupid questions. Also, how do i set JAVA_HOME?